# Class iVars not displaying in Xcode after upgrade to multiple targets

Tags: ios, xcode, ivar, ios-targets

I just updated my project to have multiple targets. After doing this, the class ivars are no longer displaying when I set a breakpoint.

[image]

I cannot figure out what might be causing this. The instructions for updating to multiple targets was pretty straight forward (see [How to Create Both a Paid and Lite Version of an iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/68613/create-paid-lite-version-iphone-app)). I'm definitely running a debug scheme, so it shouldn't be a problem of trying to debug a release version. Any suggestions?

Not sure if this is related, but those class ivars are not being retained (i.e. the particular class is a tableView and when I scroll the table view to show new rows, the class variable disappears that holds an array used for supplying data for the rows, thus resulting in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been a problem with Xcode. I restarted Xcode and the problem of the ivars not displaying went away. The problem with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is apparently a separate problem